# required_without not working with multiple fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-4.2

Laravel [`required_without`](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-required-without) is not working when I'm passing multiple fields.

This is my rules:

```
$rules = [
    'startDate' => 'date|date_format:m/d/Y|required_without:customerId,purchaseId,orderId',
    'endDate' => 'date|date_format:m/d/Y|required_without:customerId,purchaseId,orderId',
];
```

What I want, when I pass `customerId` or `purchaseId` or `orderId` (*but **not** all*) then I shouldn't be getting any error. But it is giving me any error that `startDate` is required.

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I believe, the rule you are looking for is required_without_all
IE. the startDate field must be present when all of the other specified fields (customerId,purchaseId,orderId) are not present.

As per 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation

required_without_all:foo,bar,...
The field under validation must be present and not empty only when **all** of the other specified fields are not present.

In contrast to

required_with:foo,bar,...
The field under validation must be present and not empty only if **any** of the other specified fields are present.